# Tableview not showing new added data, only shows after restarting program (javafx)

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, tableview, fxml

The tableview only shows newly added data when I restart the program.

The steps I follow to add the new item are:

1. dialogCadastro
2. Confirm the registry
3. update the table

However, updating the table does not work.

This is my code:

```
public class ControllerTelaOperacoes implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    TableView<Item> tblItem;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Item, String> colCodigoItem;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Item, String> colDescricaoItem;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Item, String> colValorItem;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Item, String> colQuantidadeItem;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Item, String> colFornecedorItem;

    @FXML
    TextField txtQuantidadeItem;

    @FXML
    TextField txtValorItem;

    @FXML
    TextField txtDescricaoItem;

    // @FXML
    // ComboBox cbxFornecedorItem;

    @FXML
    Button btnConfirmarEstoqueAtualizar;

    @FXML
    Button btnConfirmarEstoqueCadastro;

    @FXML
    TextField txtIDAtualizar;

    @FXML
    Button btnCadastrarItem;

    @FXML
    Button btnAtualizarItem;

    @FXML
    Button btnEfetuarVenda;

    private static Scene dialogEstoqueCadastrar;
    private static Scene dialogEstoqueAtualizar;
    private static Scene dialogEfetuarVenda;
    private String dados;


    public String getDados() {
        return dados;
    }

    public void setDados(String dados) {
        this.dados = dados;
    }

    @FXML
    public void CadastrarItem() throws IOException {
        tblItem.refresh();

        Parent fxmldialogEstoqueCadastro = FXMLLoader
                .load(getClass().getResource("/views/dialogEstoqueCadastrar.fxml"));
        dialogEstoqueCadastrar = new Scene(fxmldialogEstoqueCadastro);

        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();

        Image image = new Image("/img/iconeSistema.png");

        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(image);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Cadastrar item");
        primaryStage.setScene(dialogEstoqueCadastrar);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void AtualizarItem() throws IOException {
        tblItem.refresh();
        Parent fxmldialogEstoqueAtualizar = FXMLLoader
                .load(getClass().getResource("/views/dialogEstoqueAtualizar.fxml"));
        dialogEstoqueAtualizar = new Scene(fxmldialogEstoqueAtualizar);

        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();

        Image image = new Image("/img/iconeSistema.png");

        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(image);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Atualizar item");
        primaryStage.setScene(dialogEstoqueAtualizar);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void EfetuarVenda() throws IOException {
        tblItem.refresh();

        Parent fxmldialogEfetuarVenda = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/dialogEfetuarVenda.fxml"));
        dialogEfetuarVenda = new Scene(fxmldialogEfetuarVenda);

        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();

        Image image = new Image("/img/iconeSistema.png");

        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(image);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Efetuar Venda");
        primaryStage.setScene(dialogEfetuarVenda);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    // CONTROLE DE ESTOQUE

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        // conecta tabela com o bd
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            Connection con;

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/bdprojetointegrador", "root", "");

            System.out.println("TESTE TABELA 1");

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("TESTE TABELA 2");

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM item");
            System.out.println("TESTE TABELA 3");

            while (rs.next()) {
                 ObservableList<Item> dados = FXCollections
                        .observableArrayList(new Item(rs.getString("codigo"), rs.getString("descricao"),
                                rs.getString("valor"), rs.getString("quantidade"), rs.getString("fornecedor_codigo")));

                System.out.println("TESTE TABELA 4");

                tblItem.getItems().addAll(dados);
                colCodigoItem.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("codigo"));
                colDescricaoItem.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("descricao"));
                colValorItem.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("valor"));
                colQuantidadeItem.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantidade"));
                colFornecedorItem.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fornecedor_codigo"));
                System.out.println("TESTE TABELA 5");
            }

            stmt.close();
            rs.close();
            con.close();
            System.out.println("TESTE 6");

        } catch (

        ClassNotFoundException e1) {

            Alert classe = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            classe.setContentText("Classe não encontrada!");
            classe.show();

        } catch (SQLException e2) {
            // ESTÁ CHAMANDO ESTA FUNÇÃO
            Alert classe = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            classe.setContentText("Matricula já existente! ERRO: " + e2);
            classe.show();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to add the new item to the `TableView` after it's created. If all you do is save it to the database, and you only read the database on start, then it's not surprising new items only show up on a restart.

Comment: what i need to do?

Comment: After creating the item and saving it to the database, add the item to the `items` list of the `TableView`. Consider using [`Dialog`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html)s rather than rolling your own as they can return results. Also, your `TableView.refresh()` calls should not be necessary if when everything is properly configured.